Show log in page in OpenIdDict with Degraded Mode
I am setting up a new ASP.Net Core application with OpenIdDict Degraded Mode as an OAuth2 server. I initialized the server with
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(opt => { })
    .AddServer(opt =>
    {
        opt.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

        opt.SetIssuer(new Uri("http://<my-domain>"));

        opt.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("oauth2/authorize")
            .SetTokenEndpointUris("oauth2/token")
            .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("oauth2/introspect")
            .SetConfigurationEndpointUris("oauth2/.well-known/openid-configuration")
            .SetCryptographyEndpointUris("oauth2/.well-known/jwks");
 
        opt.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey();
        opt.AddEphemeralSigningKey();

        opt.EnableDegradedMode();

        opt.UseAspNetCore()
            .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();

        opt.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
        opt.RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();

        // no use in degraded mode
        opt.UseReferenceAccessTokens()
            .UseReferenceRefreshTokens();

        opt.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ProcessAuthenticationContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseInlineHandler(c =>
            {
                return default;
            });
        });
        opt.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext>(x =>
        {
            // validate client, e.g., client_id, redirect_url
            x.UseScopedHandler<ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext>();
        });
        opt.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequestContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseScopedHandler<HandleAuthorizationRequestContext>();
        });
        opt.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateIntrospectionRequestContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseInlineHandler(c =>
            {
                return default;
            });
        });

public class ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext : IOpenIddictServerHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext>
{
    public ValueTask HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext context)
    {
        if (!String.Equals(context.ClientId, "test", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            context.Reject(
                error: Errors.InvalidClient,
                description: "The specified 'client_id' doesn't match a registered application."
                );
        }
        return default;
    }
}

public class HandleAuthorizationRequestContext : IOpenIddictServerHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequestContext>
{
    public ValueTask HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleAuthorizationRequestContext context)
    {
        // play with the ClaimsPrincipal
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType);
        var claim = new Claim(Claims.Subject, "testSubject");
        claim.SetDestinations(Destinations.AccessToken);
        identity.AddClaim(claim);
        //context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        context.SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        return default;
    }
}

I find, once using an OAuth2 client to log in, the callback for ProcessAuthenticationContext (i don't know what this callback is for), ValidateAuthorizationRequestContext (check if client_id is valid) and HandleAuthorizationRequestContext (set the sub and other claims in the token) will be called sequentially. But in all of these three callbacks, I don't see any opportunities to render a log in page for user to input their user name and password. What is the best practice to do so?
